# Xamarin.Forms - Counterpart to <div> in XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to XAML / Xamarin.forms and come from a web-development background.

I am looking to make a box containing with text and images (like that can be done using a `<div>` in HTML). Please explain how to approach this with XAML & Xamarin.forms.

Also, if anybody knows a resource that lists the available tags in XAML (like w3schools for HTML), please pass that on to me.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think it just depends on how you want the element in your 'box' to behave. Like if you want them stacked, or if you want a border around them, or if you just want the box to add some padding, etc..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why not check out the [Xamarin documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/get-started-with-xaml) on this?  It is quite extensive and should help you with the basics!

There isn't a exact equivalent of a div. It depends on what you want to do. It all starts with a `Page`. You see the types of pages below.

[image: Xamarin.Forms pages]

That will be the base of your app. Within this Page you can have one `VisualElement`, which kind of forces you to use a `Layout`.

Here you see all the layouts that are available to you;

[image: Xamarin.Forms layouts]

The good news is you can nest `Layouts`!

In a Layout you can specify your controls (of type `View`).

To get back to your question; the behaviour is different than a div. If you take a `StackLayout` for example your nested controls will be stacked on top of each other and you don't have to worry about spacing, margin, etc. Another option is to go for a `Grid` which gives you a bit of flexibility.
So it's not just a container it also means something in terms of how it is placed on the screen.

I also explain some basics on my blog [here](https://blog.verslu.is/xamarin/xamarin-forms-from-zero-to-hero-part-1/) and [here](https://blog.verslu.is/xamarin/xamarin-forms-from-zero-to-hero-part-2/) but there are a lot of resources out there which can help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a Frame:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Frame x:Name="MyPanelABC">
        <Label Text="My Stuff" />
    </Frame>
</StackLayout>

private void setupPanelABC(bool isVisiblePanelABC){
    MyPanelABC.IsVisible = isVisiblePanelABC;
}
```